# Symfony User roles and accessing secure section of site

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony-security

So I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) to configure Symfony security to only allow access to the /account route where the User has logged in and has the `ROLE_USER` role

I've configured a firewall like this in `security.yaml`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/account, roles: [ROLE_USER] }
```

I've configured `User` entity like this:

```
/**
 * Class User
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @package App\Entity
 */
class User implements UserInterface
```

Here's a sample user:

```
id: 1
roles: ["ROLE_USER"]
email: email@email.com
password: --bcrypt--
```

The application allows the User to provide email and password, and if it's correct, redirects the user to `/account`.

But when they land on the `/account` page it says:

> Full authentication is required to access this resource.

So access denied basically.

security.yaml details:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

providers:
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|img|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: lazy
        provider: app_user_provider
```

Am I missing something here?

How do you complete this so this user has access to the `/account` page?

Comment: Anything in your controller that would impact this?

Comment: @ehymel it doesn't make it to the controller. The furthest it gets is inside OnKernelRequest, but there's nothing in the controller except some var dump (for testing).